# Need an Email Logging System to identify bouncing addresses, etc

Tags: email, reporting, log-analysis

My company is looking for an easy-to-use Email Logging System that can perform analysis on email logs, such as:

- Show recipients whose emails have been bouncing
- Show whether a certain email blast has been fully processed or not
- Indicate total email sent per event / per day, and how many % bounced

There is no limitation as to the kind of solution; it may be an appliance or a software, it may be open source or closed source, it may be freeware or paid.

*Note:* This requirement is driven by our marketing department, so I apologize if the requirement list is not clear. Should you need additional clarification, feel free to comment to my question, and I'll relay the need to the marketing department and try to distill their answer here.

Comment: It sounds like your organization already has e-mail delivery covered and just needs a way to analyze the logs, right? So an e-mail service with analytics, such as Mailchimp or Constant Contact, wouldn't be appropriate?

Comment: Apparently, the email blast was autogenerated by some other system. We had setup a Postfix server to handle these kinds of autogenerated email blast. The emails seem to be created 'mailmerge' style, i.e., personalized for each recipients. I'm not sure if the system generating the email can interact with external email services.

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp's [Mandrill](http://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/other-integrations/mandrill-for-mailchimp-users) could do the transactional stuff for you, while you use Mailchimp for stats and maintenance of mailing lists, templates, mailings. Mandrill is Mailchimp's motor.

My experience is that Mailchimp is strict in the e-mail addresses they allow you to use and bulk mail to. For example info@---company--- is not allowed as a recipient. It has to be personal e-mail addresses. Like hvancann@---company---. That can be annoying. Do not know wether Mandrill offers you to bypass this strict rules of their SaaS version.